# tesseract wrong output despite clear cropped image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, tesseract

i have this cropped image [image]

the output of using image_to_string with this image is 186592183
Any suggestions on how to handle this ?

```
 #cropping detected objects and passing into tesseract OCR
 A = []
 for i in indices:
     i = i[0]
     box = boxes[i]
     x = box[0]
     y = box[1]
     w = box[2]
     h = box[3]
     crop_img = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
     cv2.imwrite("Crop/crop__" + str(i) + ".jpg",crop_img)
     #Resize the image
     img = cv2.resize(crop_img, None, fx=4, fy=4)
     #Convert image to grayscale
     gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     #Convert image to black and white
     roi = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 95, 4)
     #saving the roi regions
     cv2.imwrite("Crop/roi__" + str(i) + ".jpg",roi)

     roi = cv2.threshold(roi,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

     #passing to tesseract
     #c = py.image_to_string(roi, config = '--oem 3 --psm 7 ')
     #roi = cv2.resize(roi, None, fx=0.5, fy=0.5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
     #c = py.image_to_string(roi, config = ' --psm 10 digits ')
     c = py.image_to_string(roi, config='--psm 11')

 cv2_imshow(roi)`
```

this is the original image before being cropped

[image]

Comment: If not "186592183" then what text did you want instead?

Comment: Have you tried adding the particular language used? E.g., `py.image_to_string(roi, config='--psm 11', lang='ara')`? Apologies if that's not Arabic in your image.

Comment: to clarify i just want only numbers in this case 184 2183  i wonder why 4 is considred 6 by tesseract

Comment: No OCR is perfect. To be fair to tesseract, your 4 in the cropped image is not that clear. The intersection of the horizontal and vertical bars may be interpreted as a filled circle.

Comment: You can try training tesseract with your dataset and hope the detection improves.

Comment: i tried your solution and the output now is worse  this is the output: ,83

Comment: My language suggestion was only made because I thought you wanted to capture those Arabic? characters. Again, you can try training tesseract with your dataset and hope the detection improves.

Comment: Please read the comments carefully before trying stuff willy-nilly.